# Set up ILM in the elastic stack with docker

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have Elastic Stack (version 7.5.0) running on docker. I'm trying to create ILM to delete my logs after 200mb.

Nothing seems to happened.

ilm.json

```
{
    "policy": {
        "phases": {
            "hot": {
                "actions": {
                    "rollover": {
                        "max_size": "200MB"
                    }
                }
            },
            "delete": {
                "min_age": "1d",
                "actions": {
                    "delete": {}
                }
            }
        }
}
```

filebeat.yml

```
...

setup.ilm.enabled: true
setup.ilm.rollover_alias: "filebeat"
setup.ilm.pattern: "{now/d}-000001"
setup.ilm.policy_file: "/usr/share/filebeat/ilm.json"
setup.ilm.check_exists: false
setup.ilm.overwrite: true
```

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch are you using, please also tell us what are some steps that you have done to verify that ILM is/is not working. Could you do `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_ilm/status?pretty"` with the correct port and check the running status of ILM.

Comment: Version: 7.5.0
Result of  localhost:9200/_ilm/status?pretty
`{
  "operation_mode" : "RUNNING"
}`